# Why can't VSCode provide code completions for my object?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Why doesn't VS Code figure out how to complete the methods and attributes?
When I write:
ai_game.
nothing happens, no list of methods or attributes appear

```
import pygame
 
class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship."""
    
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
```

Comment: Because you don't really define the type of "ai_game", vscode can't recognize his type and corresponding methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it has no idea what `ai_game` is. It can be any type. Add a type annotation to it for example:

```
def __init__(self, ai_game: float):
```

Well in this example I'm pretty sure you don't have a float, but it'll help VS Code to know what type is `ai_game` actually and help you with its methods..